# Will the c# compiler perform multiple implicit conversions to get from one type to another?

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

Let's say you have yourself a class like the following:

```
public sealed class StringToInt { 
    private string _myString; 
    private StringToInt(string value) 
    { 
        _myString = value; 
    } public static implicit operator int(StringToInt obj) 
    { 
        return Convert.ToInt32(obj._myString); 
    } 
    public static implicit operator string(StringToInt obj) 
    { 
        return obj._myString; 
    } 
    public static implicit operator StringToInt(string obj) 
    { 
        return new StringToInt(obj); 
    } 
    public static implicit operator StringToInt(int obj) 
    { 
        return new StringToInt(obj.ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

Will you then be able to write code like the following:

```
MyClass.SomeMethodThatOnlyTakesAnInt(aString);
```

without it stating that there is no implicit cast from string to int?

[Yes, i could test it myself but i thought i would put it out there and see what all of the gurus have to say]

Comment: "Yes, i could test it myself but i thought i would put it out there and see what all of the gurus have to say" - that's a strange sentence.  You did all that effort to generate that class, but you didn't hit F5?

Comment: Sounds like you should test it yourself like you said and post an answer, but I'm no guru.

Comment: I wrote it in the SO question box. :D

Comment: try copy and pasting into Visual Studio....

Comment: There, i tested it. You all happy now?

Comment: I had to put the following in my code today: "MyByteVar = (byte)(int)(MyValue * 255.0 / 100.0)" because C# couldn't cast from a float or double to a byte.  So, no, sometimes you just need to do the double cast.

Comment: Michael Petrotta it sounds like you underestimate the relevance of expert opinion.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: Allowing multiple hops would lead to ambiguity, potentially it would be possible to go from A-X-C or A-Y-C, the compiler would have no reason to pick one route over another. The spec for implicit conversions says they should not cause data loss, so either should produce the same result but I guess the C# language team decided that this provided to much scope for cock up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain this is not possible under C# 3.0. The sections in [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) that covers conversions is 6.4. Namely, 6.4.4 "User-defined implicit conversions".

It only talks about conversions from S->T (and not S->T->U) which covers the cases such as:

```
StringToInt _t = "foo";
int t = _t;
```

and

```
int t = (StringToInt)"foo";
```

Where both of these cases only involve S->T (twice).

I am pretty sure this is not possible in C# 3.0.
Allowing S->T->U would require *much more* work to be performed by the type matcher, at least following the algorithm specified.

Answer (score 10):

No C# won't call more than one user defined implicit conversion.  From the C# spec section 6.4.3:

> Evaluation of a user-defined conversion never involves more than one user-defined or lifted conversion operator. In other words, a conversion from type S to type T will never first execute a user-defined conversion from S to X and then execute a user-defined conversion from X to T.

Comment: other wise you could cheat by having transient types just to convert anything to anything.

Comment: `cheat by having transient types` ..like in good ol' c++.. sometimes I really miss that

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to work. It requires at least one explicit cast. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Typos in your snippet:

```
public StringToInt(string value)
{
    _myString = value;
}
public static implicit operator int(StringToInt obj)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(obj._myString);
}
public static implicit operator string(StringToInt obj)
{
    return obj._myString;
}
```

If `aString` is of type `StringToInt`, your usage should work.

Comment: Yup i caught those, but i may point out that the goal is to get an implicit cast from string to int...

Comment: Since you can't extend the built-in types, you can't create new implicit conversions for them. Intuitively I wouldn't expect the compiler to allow this. It would seem indeterminate which classes the compiler would look at to determine a possible chain of implicit conversions. Also the readability of such code seems awful, not to mention resolving conflicts when you pass a variable to a method family that has overloads for that variable type as well as something it can implicitly be converted to.