# Runtime implicit cast from object

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

We created `Id32` and `Id64` struct to wrap integers and long values coming from DB, so they can be explicitly processed as IDs by a Json converter (with dedicated custom converters).

The problem is that we read this data from a `Dictionary<string, object>` that actually is a `DataRow`-like object where the `string` part is the name of the column and the `object` part is the value.

So *before* we had this code to read the value:

```
int myVal = (int)row["COLUMN"]
```

We want this code to continue working also after these changes.

But since `row["COLUMN"]` is an `object` (@ compile-time) the implicit cast fails, even though it is actually an `Id32` (@ run-time).

The following obviously works:

```
int myVal = (Id32)row["COLUMN"]
```

But is there some to way to fix this **without modifying** the code that reads the value?

This is the struct code:

```
public struct Id32
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public Id32(int id) { this.Value = id; }

    public static implicit operator int(Id32 id) { return id.Value; }

    public static implicit operator Id32(int id) { return new Id32(id); }
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611083/will-the-c-sharp-compiler-perform-multiple-implicit-conversions-to-get-from-one

Comment: This question is about implicit conversions, not casts. Though casting is involved (you have an `object` and it needs to be cast to `int`, possibly inside of an implicit conversion from `object` defined on `Id32`).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not possible with the constraint not to modify your *retrieving code* `int myVal = (int)row["COLUMN"]`.

You would need to add an implicit cast to `object` (to `int`) which cannot be done. There are many ways to make your own cast simple but everyone I can think of or you will find like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393441/implicit-cast-operator-from-object) requires to change that line.

Even if you not change it I guess you will have to recompile it - so if you recompile it, why not change it? There are some refactoring tools which should make even thousands of that lines quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for your contribute.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion not a very decent solution, but it works (hope there are better solutions): if you use `dynamic` the underlying type is determined on run-time, so the type check with the implicit cast will work.

The code I have used:

```
dynamic o = new Id32(1);
// dynamic o = row["COLUMN"]; in your case

int myVal = (int)o;
```

If you change `dynamic` to `object` you will have your current situation, which fails.

Comment: This is interesting indeed. But I don't really know if it's possible to declare a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`... I'll give it a try.

Comment: No, but it is converted at that time already (if you do this before adding to the dictionary), so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, that way, we need to modify the code to read the value anyway.

Comment: Well that works surprisingly, but as you stated - this is a dirty solution. (``var row = new Dictionary<string, dynamic> { {"COLUMN", new Id32(42)} };``)

Comment: Okay, my bad. A dictionary with `Value` type `dynamic` will work too.

Comment: `dynamic` does not exist in the CLR type system. If the C# code doing the cast is expecting an `object` nothing dynamic will happen. You need to modify it so that it considers the dictionary to have dynamic values.